# c++ why cascade shared object linkage

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

In my lib directory, I see most of the shared object linkage are cascades. For example:

```
libctest.so.1.0 -> libctest.so.1
libctest.so.1 -> libctest.so
```

I know the link of `libctest.so` is to make the compile flag `-lctest` to work, but what's the point of having `libctest.so.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wrote the filnames in the reverse order as to how it is normally shown, you would have 3 files

```
libctest.so.1.0  (library file)
libctest.so.1 -> libctest.so.1.0 (symlink to the libctest.so.1.0 file)
libctest.so -> libctest.so.1     (symlink to the libctest.so.1 symlink
```

It is a versioning scheme.

A particular release/installation of a library has a full filename, e.g. `libctest.so.1.0` , embedded into this library is the [SONAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) , a logical name of the library, e.g. `libctest.so.1` that is also used as a symlink to the actual file.

When linking an executable, the library SONAME is added to the executable, so at runtime the executable will look for a filename of `libctest.so.1`. The convention is to have the SONAME of a the library stay the same as long as it is backwards compatible, and to change it when backwards incompatible ABI changes are introduced.

And as you say, the linker will will look for `lib*.so` when you do the linking.

This way executables (or other libraries) that are linked to `libctest.so.1` can remain unchanged when `libctest` is upgraded. Thus when libctest version 1.1 is released, you might have these files:

```
libctest.so.1.1
libctest.so.1 -> libctest.so.1.1
libctest.so -> libctest.so.1
```

Executables still try to locate libctest.so.1 and can therefore remain unchanged when the library is upgraded. The library must be written so it's backwards compatible for this to work in practice though.

If you release a new backwards incompatible library, the convention is to change the SONAME of that library, so you end up with e.g.

```
libctest.so.2.0
libctest.so.2 -> libctest.so.2.0
```

This supports having several incompatible versions of a library installed on a system if different exeucatbles need different versions of that library.

Comment: if the name of actual `so` file is `libctest.so.199`, I only need to create a link `libctest.so -> libctest.so.199`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are all about versioning. This means you can easily have multiple versions of a library installed simultaneously, and applications linked with a specific version will use that (since the linker resolves the symbolic filesystem links).